# Automation tool for configuration, installation and editing tasks

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, configuration, automation

I'm looking for a tool that you could write to automate tasks as you want, for example, installation of LAMP package:

```
install package A
install package B
...
modify configure file of package B in line 12, column 23, add or remove the string 'extension=xdebug'
configure SSL
etc
etc
```

then you run that file like:

```
$ tool exec conf.yml
```

Then, I want to undo the tasks I would run:

```
$ tool rollback conf.yml
```

Running it would back to original state without install and configure the packages. Is there a tool that makes that in Ubuntu system?

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of the `man` pages?

Comment: i don't have problems using the man pages, the main issue is not understanding the use of the commands, the main issue is automate repetitive tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for ansible or alternative like saltstack, puppet or chef.

Ansible works with playbooks that you run. Those will ssh to the hosts you want and become with sudo use installation commands. Ansible uses python and Ansible modules that execute tasks that you defined in your YAML. There is a file edit module that can replace or add lines.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ansible-to-install-and-set-up-lamp-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thats what I want, I didn't knew about these tools, these tools could rollback if fail processing the tasks?

Comment: Rollback will be tough no matter which tool you use. There is a rescue section and you can do a reverse of the installation steps, but when something really goes wrong, only skill and troubleshooting can save you

Comment: Well, git does a reliable rollback in source code you are working on. I would like to use a feature reliable as this.

Comment: For databases you can use atomic actions and rollbacks. But for the filesystem you have to consider open files by all types of processes. The best tool in the box is using snapshots before making filesystem changes. But I'm a bigger fan of recreating from scratch

Comment: Snapshots is a good concept to mantain data integrity. That is exactly the idea I thought from start, recreate same config for the sites I'm working on in a reliable and standardized maner. One good example is Docker, but in that case I can't use it.